# Martingale property for stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

We have the following theorem:

> Let $M$ be a square integrable martingale, that is $\sup_{t\geq 0}E[M_t^2]<\infty$. Furthermore, let $H$ predictable s.t. $$E[\int_0^\infty H_u^2 d[M,M]_u]<\infty$$. Then $H\bullet M$ is a square integrable martingale.

I am wondering if the theorem is still true if we replace the condition $E[\int_0^\infty H^2 d[M,M]]<\infty$ with $E[\int_0^\infty H^2 d\langle M,M\rangle]<\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Since for square integrable martingale $M$, $\langle M,M\rangle=[M,M]^p$ is the predictable dual projection of $[M,M]$, hence for predictable $H$, $\mathsf{E}[\int_0^\infty H^2\mathrm{d}\langle M,M\rangle]=\mathsf{E}[\int_0^\infty H^2\mathrm{d}[M,M]]$.

Comment: Are you using that $\mathsf{E}[\int_0^\infty H^2\mathrm{d}([M]-[M]^p)]=0$? Clearly, $H^2\bullet([M]-[M]^p)$ is a local martingale, but why is the expectation zero?

Comment: I found theorem 3.17 in chapter 1 of Jacod/Shyraev, which states that $E[(H\bullet A^p)_\infty]=E[(H\bullet A)_\infty]$ for all non-negative predictable processes $H$ is equivalent to $A-A^p$ is a local martingale. Furthermore, $\langle M\rangle =[M]^p$ is proposition 4.50 in chapter 1. Thanks.

Comment: @peer Firstly, $\langle M\rangle=[M]^p$, i.e., $\langle M\rangle$ is the compensantor(dual predictable  projection) of $[M]$ ; secondly, $\mathsf{E}[(H^2\cdot \langle M\rangle)_\infty]=\mathsf{E}[(H^2\cdot [M])_\infty] $ by theorem 3.17(iii) in chapter 1 of Jacod/Shyraev. Thank you for your question.